# How to change a value in yaml file with a bash command?

Tags: bash, yaml, yq

I have this yaml file:

```
id:
  providerName: admin
  apiName: LagerAPI
  version: 1.0.0
uuid: 1297c3e5-24aa-4806-be05-0cc3f2decaff
type: HTTP
context: /wso/1.0.0
contextTemplate: /wso/{version}
tags: []
documents: []
lastUpdated: Apr 14, 2020 4:33:37 PM
```

and wanna change it the value **wso** in lines **context:** and **contextTemplate:** to **test**, that this will be the result:

```
id:
  providerName: admin
  apiName: LagerAPI
  version: 1.0.0
uuid: 1297c3e5-24aa-4806-be05-0cc3f2decaff
type: HTTP
context: /test/1.0.0
contextTemplate: /test/{version}
tags: []
documents: []
lastUpdated: Apr 14, 2020 4:33:37 PM
```

How do I do this with a **bash command**?

Thank you :)

Comment: If you are ok to using an answer using `yq`, I can add up an answer

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

```
sed -i 's/wso/test/' file.yaml
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case there are more `wso` in that file this should replace what was intended.

```
sed '/^context/s/wso/test/;/^contextTemplate/s/wso/test/' file.yml
```